# form with js, html, not hidden fields at first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a problem with a field, 
code 
HTML

```
<span id="sudaner">
  <input type="radio" name="traveledis" checked value="0" >No
  <input type="radio" name="traveledis" value="1" />Yes
</span>

<div id="sudandetails">`
```

and this is the js code

```
$("#sudaner input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
        $("#sudandetails").css("display","block");
        $("#countries").prop('required',true);
        $("#bcfrom").prop('required',true);
        $("#bcto").prop('required',true);
        $("#country_reason").prop('required',true);
    }
    else {
        $("#countries").prop('required',false);
        $("#countries").val("");
        $("#bcfrom").prop('required',false);
        $("#bcfrom").val("");
        $("#bcto").prop('required',false);
        $("#bcto").val("");
        $("#country_reason").prop('required',false);
        $("#country_reason").val("");
        $("#sudandetails").css("display","none");
    }
});
```

I have *'checked'* active in *'NO'* but when I go to the form, I see the *'No'* in default but the fields aren't hidden at first. I need to move the selection by *'Yes'* and again *'No'* and the fields are hidden or click 2 times in 'No' and the fields are hidden. so I don't understand why the field aren't hidden at first.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don`t forget to accept an answer as correct if it fits to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle for you and combined the `ready` function with the `click` function in an own handler. You can't only check the value `on click` because there is no click if the document gets loaded, so nothing happens.

https://jsfiddle.net/ww582Lj9/

```
function myHandler(e) {
    if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
          $("#sudandetails").css("display","block");
          $("#countries").prop('required',true);
          $("#bcfrom").prop('required',true);
          $("#bcto").prop('required',true);
          $("#country_reason").prop('required',true);
      }
      else {
          $("#countries").prop('required',false);
          $("#countries").val("");
          $("#bcfrom").prop('required',false);
          $("#bcfrom").val("");
          $("#bcto").prop('required',false);
          $("#bcto").val("");
          $("#country_reason").prop('required',false);
          $("#country_reason").val("");
          $("#sudandetails").css("display","none");
      }
}

$(document).ready(myHandler);
$("#sudaner input[type='radio']").on("click", myHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide this div initially. add this line in you script

```
$("#sudandetails").hide();
```

You bind an event on click and when page load click event not trigger.